# Choosing mutually exclusive pairs efficiently

Tags: algorithm

This is a problem that could be done with some type of brute-force algorithm, but I was wondering if there are some efficient ways of doing this.

Let's assume that we have the following pairs of integers

```
 (1, 3), (2, 5), (4, 7), (2, 7), (10, 9)
```

We want to figure out what is the maximum number of mutually exclusive pairs.

By mutually exclusive pair, I mean pairs such that they do not have any 
common integer.

For instance, we cannot choose both (2, 5), (2, 7) since both pairs contain 2.

In the above case, 4 would be a solution as we can choose the following mutually exclusive pairs:

```
      (1, 3), (2, 5), (4, 7), (10, 9)
```

thus 4 maximum pairs total.

I was wondering if there are efficient ways of doing so.

Comment: I don't see any non-brute-force approach to this without knowing ahead of time the order and values in the data.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: @user98235 I thought I had a solution, and I thought it might be easier to explain in the language you are using. I don't think my idea will work though. I was thinking of using a hash set. But I realized I don't know what the hash function would look like.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your question is equivalent to finding a maximum matching on a graph. The nodes of your graph are integers, and your pairs (a, b) are edges of the graph. A matching is a set of pairwise non-adjacent edges, which is equivalent to saying the same integer doesn't appear in two edges.

A polynomial time solution to this problem is the [Blossom algorithm also known as Edmond's algorithm.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blossom_algorithm) It's rather too complicated to include the details in the answer here.

Comment: This is the best solution.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**: As my misunderstanding, the previous approach is not correct.

Here is my **second attempt**:

If we view each number in a pair as node in a graph, we can build a bipartite graph, with edges between each node if there is a pair containing these two nodes.

So, this problem is reduced to find the [maximum bipartite matching](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-bipartite-matching/), which can be solved using classic [Ford-fulkerson algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford%E2%80%93Fulkerson_algorithm).

**First wrong approach:**

<s>We can solve this by using dynamic programming.</s>

Sorting the pair by their starting point, (if draw, by their ending point).

Assume that we have a function `f`, with `f(i)` returns the maximum number of pairs, if we choose from pair `i` onward.

If we select a pair `i`, we need to check what is the next smallest index greater than `i` that is not overlapping with `i`.

We have

```
f(i) = max(1 + f(next index not overlap i), f (i + 1))
```

Storing the result of `f(i)` in a table, we can have a solution with **O(n^2)** time complexity, and the result will be `f(0)`.

Pseudo code:

```
sort data;//Assume we have a data array to store all pairs
int[] dp;
int f(int index){
    if(index == data.length)
       return 0;  
    if(we have calculated this before)
       return dp[index];
    int nxt = -1;
    for(int i = index + 1; i < data.length; i++){
        if(data[i].start > data[index].end){
           nxt = i;
           break; 
        }
    }
    if(nxt == -1)
      return dp[index] = max(1, f(index + 1));
    return dp[index] = max(1 + f(nxt) , f(index + 1));
}
```

Comment: I think you can improve on this, with some memoization. Notice that there are 2 operations in `f(i)`.... So you can have a matrix, where `memo[i][0]` means you took `i` and `memo[i][1]` means you didn't take it.

Comment: @Hock I think `memo[i]` is enough, as we don't need to know whether we take pair `i` or not, but memoization is correct approach, thank for the suggestion :)

Comment: I think you'd need the second index to rebuild the "path" (?) and know which pairs are the ones in the answer?

Comment: Well. this isn't an interval overlap problem that I am asking. (1, 3), (2, 4) are considered to be disjoint pairs in the question.

Comment: @user98235 hmm, you are right, revising my answer :)

Comment: Again, we have the same idea, but I think you made a mistake: the graph's not necessarily bipartite.

Comment: @Hock, actually, we can easily rebuild the path by using this to check whether or not we can use index `i`  `if(result == 1 + f(nxt index not overlap i))` , and update the `result` accordingly, but well, this answer is not valid actually.

Answer (score 2):

This problem can be recast in terms of graph theory. Nodes of the graph are the pairs you are given. Two nodes are connected if the pairs have a number in common. Your problem is to find a maximum independent set.

Maximum independent set is equivalent to finding a maximum clique, which is both NP-complete and "hard to approximate". However, in this particular case, the graphs are of a special type called "claw-free" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claw-free_graph) because if a node is connected to three other nodes, at least two of those nodes must share a common number and so are themselves connected.

It turns out that for the special case of claw-free graphs, the maximum independent set problem can be solved in polynomial time: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claw-free_graph#Independent_sets.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** This won't work as user98235 points out in the comments. I will leave this here however in case anyone else has the same idea.

I think this will work if I have understood the problem correctly.

Pseudocode:

```
resultList = new List of Pair
elementSet = new Set of int

for pair in inputPairs:

    if not elementSet.Contains(pair.First) and not elementSet.Contains(pair.Second):
        elementSet.Add(pair.First)
        elementSet.Add(pair.Second)
        resultList.Add(pair)
```

The time complexity will be O(N).

Comment: I don't think it works. For instance, let's assume we're given the following list of pairs { (1, 2), (2, 3), (1, 4) }, then the algorithm results in {(1, 2)}, but the optimal algorithm would output { (2, 3), (1, 4) }

Comment: or I may be misunderstanding your answer. please correct me if that's the case.

Comment: @user98235, yes, you are right. This won't work. Wow, that is hard. It is an optimization problem.