# Efficient algorithm for finding max number of pairs

Tags: c++, algorithm

What would be the fastest way to find pairs of numbers from a list of pair of numbers such that maximum number of pairs are formed?

**For e.g:** I have 6 numbers: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

Following are the valid pairs:

```
0 1
0 2
0 3
1 4
3 5
```

Now, once a number is included in a pair, the number cannot be included in another pair.

*That is, if I chose the pair 0 1, I cannot again chose 0 2 as I have already used 0 once.*

I need to choose pairs from the list of valid pairs such that I get maximum number of pairs.

**As per the example:**

If I choose the following pairs:

```
0 1
3 5
```

*Note that I'll be able to chose only these two pairs such that no number is repeated and 2 and 4 will be left.*

But If I choose the following pairs:

```
0 2
1 4
3 5
```

I get three pairs and no number is left alone. Similarly from a given list, I need to calculate the maximum number of pairs I can make. What would be the most efficient way to do it?

Comment: This problem smell like NP-hard.. Can anyone confirm? Is this a variant of vertex cover problem?

Comment: @vincentleest definitely.

Comment: @vincentleest: it looks like the [maximum matching problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29) which is in **P**.

Comment: Why are `(0, 4)`, `(0, 5)`, `(2, 4)`, `(1, 5)`, `(2, 5)` not valid pairs? Or are you just given a list of pairs and you need to choose a maximal subset?

Comment: @BillLynch: out of the list of edges (if you see these pairs as edges), you need to generate the subset with the largest number of edges, such that no two vertices share a vertex.

Comment: Your question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29552742/choosing-mutually-exclusive-pairs-efficiently/29553489#29553489

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem can be solved in polynomial time complexity using Bloossom algorithm:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blossom_algorithm

Form a graph where each number is node and connect each pair with edge. Run the above mentioned algorithm on this graph to find solution.

Answer (score 2):

So your valid pairs could be represented as a graph, and then the maximum number of pairs is a maximum matching in that graph.

Note that you can have multiple solutions. For valid pairs [(0,1),(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)] both [(0, 1), (2, 3)] and [(1, 2), (3, 4)] are solutions.

Comment: U mean calculating longest path using DFS ?

Comment: @bayblade567: A simple greedy algorithm is sufficient... See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29#Maximal_matchings)...

Comment: There is a difference between maximum and maximal matching.

Comment: @riko, you're right. guess they want maximal.

Comment: @Riko: euh indeed, read too fast and shared two wrong [reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29#In_general_graphs)... sorry.