# How to pick valid pairs of integers from a list optimally?

Tags: list, algorithm, sorting, language-agnostic, matching

### Summary

Given a discrete list of integers, assign as many of the integers as possible to unique pairs that satisfy a condition.  How do I choose these pairs optimally so I have the fewest integers left over?

### Details

- I have a list of 100 integers from 1 to ~1000000000.
- Each integer can only be used once.
- Integers are assigned to pairs `(a, b)` such that, let's say, `2 * a != greatestCommonDenominator(a, a + b)`.
- The program returns the set of pairs that could be created with the fewest number of integers left over.

### Problems:

- Each integer can have more than one valid pair, but only one can be made with it.
- List is not sorted, though it can be.
- Integers in the list are not unique, meaning I have to work with indices.

I already have the functions for checking the conditions in place, I just can't figure out a functional strategy for scanning the list.

Considering how unlikely it is for a pairing to be invalid given this condition, I've tried finding the pairs I *can't* make first, then taking the members of each of those pairs and placing them with a different integer so they can't be invalid.  From there I figure I could pair the rest arbitrarily.  Of course, that ended up being far too convoluted and had a lot of redundancy in my implementation.

While I work on figuring out *my* system, does anyone have any better strategies I could try?

Comment: This issue is admittedly similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29552742/choosing-mutually-exclusive-pairs-efficiently, though I don't understand the wording of the solution to said post.

Comment: If the reply noted by @ABadHaiku is correct, then this is a duplicate question. I agree that this question sounds like `maximum matching on a graph`.

Comment: If you draw pictures by hand, IMO the problem and solution become much more intuitive.